# How to aggregate time series data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, time-series, aggregation-framework

I have MongoDB documents like the ones explained here https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

So 1 document for each day (and type and system) with a `values` field that contains hours, minutes and seconds data, so like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fc57d75bc7315366b78799"), 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "system" : "192-168-1-30", 
    "type" : "memory", 
    "values" : {
        [...]
        "11" : { // hour 11
            [...]
            "49" : { // minute 49
                [...]
                "43" : NumberInt(62171000), // second 43
                "44" : NumberInt(62169000),
                [...]
            }, 
            "50" : {
                "1" : NumberInt(62363000), 
                "2" : NumberInt(62319000)
                [...]
            },
            [...]
        },
        [...]
    }, 
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-03T13:34:00.720+0000"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-03T11:49:43.442+0000")
}
```

Here for example at 11:49:43 of 2017-11-03 memory was at 62171000.

Now I'm trying to get aggregated data of these documents to obtain rows with average data for each minutes, hours and so on but I'm confused how to tell to the aggregation framework that $values is an array of hours, minutes and seconds.

Or should I use map/reduce?

Any hints?

Comment: Is it for **each** 60 seconds, 1 hrs and so on, or **last** 60 seconds, 1 hrs and so on ?

Comment: Mmmh what do you mean? I get data almost each second, I'd like to have it average aggregated by minutes, hours and so on.

Comment: Oh I saw th part you are speaking about. "For *each*", updating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing essential point of the article which basically describes a system with pre-aggregated data:

> The fields “num_samples” and “total_samples” are updated as new readings are applied to the document:

```
{$set: {“values.59”: 2000000 }},
{$inc: {num_samples: 1, total_samples: 2000000 }}
```

So that each document contains number of values and total of values **per document**. So if you added these 2 fields to your document you could easily calculate **daily** average by dividing total_values by number_values.

The article is quite old. From one hand Mongodb significantly evolved since then, from the other hand projects mentioned there got abandoned. I am particularly sorry for the destiny of Square Cube one.

Starting from v3.4 you can benefit from [objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to achieve runtime grouping as following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project:{        
        date : 1, system : 1, type : 1,
        hour: {$objectToArray: "$values" } 
    }},
    {$unwind: "$hour"},    
    {$project:{ 
        date : 1, system : 1, type : 1,
        hour: "$hour.k",
        minute: {$objectToArray: "$hour.v" } 
    }},
    {$unwind: "$minute"},    
    {$project:{ 
        date : 1, system : 1, type : 1, hour: 1,
        minute: "$minute.k",
        second: {$objectToArray: "$minute.v" } 
    }},
    {$unwind: "$second"},    
    {$project:{ 
        date : 1, system : 1, type : 1, hour: 1, minute: 1,
        second: "$second.k",
        value: "$second.v"
    }},
])
```

Which gives you 1 document per second in following format:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fc57d75bc7315366b78799"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "system" : "192-168-1-30",
    "type" : "memory",
    "hour" : "11",
    "minute" : "49",
    "second" : "43",
    "value" : 62171000
}
```

You can apply aggregation stages after that to group by seconds, minutes, hours.

The problem is it is quite expensive, and the fact that hours, minutes, and seconds are strings, only makes it more complex to manipulate.

It would be way simpler to store 1 document per second in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, so do you think is more productive to have lot of documents instead of this (old) approach? I know that could be more and more easy to save 1 doc per second but I think I would have a huge collection of records (I have to monitor 10k systems).

Comment: @Michelem you hit the nail with this follow up question. Pre-aggregated data is a niche approach for the systems where volume of data doesn't allow to aggregate it runtime. If having 1 document per second results with too slow aggregation, the code in the answer wont help, as it is even more expensive. You may want to pre-aggregate on per-minute base and do higher level aggregation runtime.